# file.getas('application/pdf') is changing embedded urls to be google.com query

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Slide document using AppScript. The slide contains an embedded URL inserted into a textbox by using the following code:

textStyle.setLinkUrl("https://www.apple.com");

The generated Slide document has the correct embedded URL. However when I convert the slide document to a PDF document using the following code, the URL is changed to the below. This causes a redirection when the link is clicked on in a PDF viewer.

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.apple.com&sa=D&ust=1587520665890000&usg=AFQjCNFxTpL_mRUtgTWoi4Zgz97trJNIEg

This code converts the Slide document to PDF:

`var pdfBlob = slideFile.getAs('application/pdf');
pdfBlob.setName(slideFile.getName() + ".pdf");
var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob);`

Oddly enough if I open the Slide document from the Google Drive using the browser interface, and choose Download -> PDF, it generates the PDF document with the correct url (https://www.apple.com).

So  I have verified that the URL is correct in the Slide document. I don't understand why the conversion to PDF using the getAs interface from AppScript is changing the url in the target PDF document yet the Google user interface is not doing this on the same document.

I get the feeling that Google is adding information for my application so it can do some form of tracking on the document that was created by my application. But I can't seem to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

When the Google Slides file is converted to the PDF format by `DriveApp.getFileById(###).getAs('application/pdf')` and `DriveApp.getFileById(###).getBlob()`, the hyperlinks become like your issue. I think that this might be the specification at Google side. When you want to use the original URL in the converted PDF format, please use the endpoint for exporting to the PDF format. The endpoint can be retrieved from `exportLinks` of the method of Files: get in Drive API v3.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
var fileId = "###";  // Please set the Google Slides ID.

var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=" + fileId;
var pdfBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getBlob();
var slideFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
pdfBlob.setName(slideFile.getName() + ".pdf");
var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob);
```

#### References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)